# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm making a crud in fastapiI have a user model and I created another one called showuser to only show some specific fields in the query, but when I execute the request I get an error.

I just want my request to show the fields I have in showuser.

my schemas

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from datetime import datetime

# Create a User model
# Create a class for the user


class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str
    name: str
    lastname: str
    address: Optional[str] = None
    telephone: Optional[int] = None
    email: str
    creation_user: datetime = datetime.now()

# Create UserId model
# Create a class for the UserId
class UserId(BaseModel):
    id: int

# Create a ShowUser model
# Create a class for the ShowUser
class ShowUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    name: str
    lastname: str
    email: str
    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

and this is the code from user where I implement the api

```
@router.get('/{user_id}', response_model=ShowUser)
def get_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    if not user:
        return {"Error": "User not found"}
    return {"User": user}
```

Terminal Message

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for ShowUser 
response -> username
  field required (type-value_error.missing)
response -> name
  field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> lastname
  field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> email
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Comment: Why `return {"User": user}`? You explicitly set `response_model=ShowUser`. Just return the `user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the return value of your `get_user` function is the issue. Rather than returning `{"User": user}`, try returning just the `user` object as shown below:

```py
@router.get('/{user_id}', response_model=ShowUser)
def get_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    if not user:
        return {"Error": "User not found"}
    return user
```

EDIT: The same error will occur if the database does not contain a  `User` object matching the value of `user_id`. Rather than returning `{"Error": "User not found"}`, the best way to handle this very common scenario is to raise an `HTTPException` with a `404` status code and error message:

```py
@router.get('/{user_id}', response_model=ShowUser)
def get_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=int(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND),
            detail=f"No user exists with user.id = {user_id}"
        )
    return user
```